# JsonGenerationException in Jackson 2.9.0.pr1

Tags: java, jersey, jackson

I updated `jersey` to 2.25.1 and `jackson` to 2.9.0.pr1 and I started getting `JsonGenerationException`. It seems like `JsonGenerationException.class` exists in the `jackson-core` package but still I am getting this error. Is there a way to debug this, because I've updated the projects using Maven and I even changed the scope of this dependency to `provided` jut to make sure it is available @ runtime but no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, after a some debugging I found out that some of the classes still had the old references of `JsonGenerationmException.class` and usually by cleaning the project the compiler points out the errors but in this case for some reason the compiler was happy. Only JUnits were failing  with the `initialization error` which could potentially divert my debugging process. I had to switch all the old references with the new ones and with a little code change in some classes the error went away and all of the apps started perfectly. 
I hope this may help some devs.